# sendkeys does not seem to be working in vba

Tags: vba, excel, sendkeys

I am trying to use an excel add in in VBA. Unfortunately recording the macro doesn't seem to work and hence the reason I want to try use the keyboard shortcuts. The shortcut I am after is ALT X 2 V. I have tried using `SendKeys.send ("%{x}{2}{v}")`

but every time I try to use it, the code write the values "2v" to my vba screen. I am not sure I have fully understood how to use this method as I want the actions to be actioned in excel so that I can access this add in.

I have been through the forums but can't seem to get an answer, which includes putting a wait command between each keystroke. Could really do with some help.

Comment: Why are you using SendKeys? In my humble opinion it should _always_ be avoided at _all_ costs.

Answer (score 0):

Try `SendKeys "%x2v"`
That said, using sendkeys is almost always a Bad Idea. I understand that you're trying to call some function from an addin, but if you're able to access that code at all, I would do so, and call whatever you're trying to run directly. At some point, SendKeys *will* mess something up.

Comment: like turning off numbers lock